# Form an unstructured record into structured record in UNIX script

Tags: text-processing, text-formatting

Using *UNIX* script the following code to be developed.

I have a file 20-40 GB data contains data like below. Providing sample records.

```
AUTO="text1" CAR="its mine" LORRY="commercial vehicle" CART="simple " BULLCART="same old one simple with bull" TRUCK="Multi purpose"
AUTO="text2" BUS="commercial vehicle" LORRY="its a vehicle" CART="without bull" BULLCART="with bull" TRUCK="Multi purpose"
AUTO="text3" BUS="commercial vehicle" CAR="Personal" LORRY="mini one ?" BULLCART="bull" TRUCK="Multi purpose"
AUTO="" CART="simple without bull" BULLCART="nothing spl with bull" TRUCK="Multi purpose"
AUTO="long text" BUS="commercial vehicle" CAR="jubel" BULLCART="" TRUCK="Multi purpose"
AUTO="message" CAR="others" LORRY="commercial vehicle" BULLCART="not null" TRUCK="Multi purpose"
AUTO="cleverwiz" BUS="commercial vehicle" CAR="yours" LORRY="max vehicle" CART="bull is there" TRUCK="Multi purpose"
AUTO="passengers only" BUS="commercial vehicle" CAR="ramsoh" LORRY="maintainable " CART="old one" BULLCART="simple with bull"
```

the order of fields are AUTO, BUS, CAR, LORRY, CART, BULLCART, TRUCK

Expected output should be, if in case CAR is not present, then need to insert 3rd field CAR=""; if no LORRY, then insert LORRY="" as 4th field.

If you look at the 1st record BUS is not there, need to insert BUS="" as second field. so the output will be

```
AUTO="text1" BUS="" CAR="its mine" LORRY="commercial vehicle" CART="simple " BULLCART="same old one simple with bull" TRUCK="Multi purpose"
```

4th record BUS, CAR, LORRY are not there, so, need to insert BUS="" CAR="". The output will be

```
AUTO="" BUS="" CAR="" LORRY="" CART="simple without bull" BULLCART="nothing spl with bull" TRUCK="Multi purpose"
```

Comment: You can edit your own question if you have additional details, no need to comment. Also, is the output shown the full result based on the sample records? If not please indicate the full result you expect to get based on the input shown. And if you have some working code fragments please add them as well.

Comment: You seem to want to normalise the data, so that every row contains seven assignments, in the same order each time. Is that correct?

Comment: We're not really a script-writing service. What have you tried so far?

Comment: i tried with if else case but stuck in between. hence posed the query.

Answer (score 0):

One might say that giving away ready solutions is not nice, but if you ask. here you go:

```
#!/bin/bash


#  AUTO, BUS, CAR, LORRY, CART, BULLCART, TRUCK

get_param(){
    param=`echo $1|sed -E  '/.*\b('$2'\=\"[^"]*\").*/!d;s/.*\b('$2'\=\"[^"]*\").*/\1/'`

    if [ -z "$param" ]; then 
        param=$2'=""'
    fi
    echo $param;
}
process_line(){
    auto=`get_param "$1" 'AUTO'`
    bus=`get_param "$1" 'BUS'`
    car=`get_param "$1" 'CAR'`
    lorry=`get_param "$1" 'LORRY'`
    cart=`get_param "$1" 'CART'`
    bullcart=`get_param "$1" 'BULLCART'`
    truck=`get_param "$1" 'TRUCK'`
    echo $auto $bus $car $lorry $cart $bullcart $truck 
}

while read LINE;do
        process_line "$LINE"
done < source.txt
```